# Bokeh line graph, Is there a way to set the line color as gradient?

Tags: python, bokeh, gradient

I have a very simple spaghetti graph like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfhq.png)

I would like to set the line color as a gradient.
Does anyone know whether this is possible or not?
I searched for an hour but could not find any solution...

Here is a part of my code:

```
p = figure(title="stabilogram", x_axis_label='time', y_axis_label='position', plot_width=900, plot_height=900)
p.line(x='posX', y='posY', line_width=2, source=df_trial)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh 2.3.1 there is no option to set line shades to anything other than a single color. The closest workaround would be to split your line up into multiple segments (which could be plotted with `segments`), and set their colors individually.